# SignalR wont work inside an AngularJS service, why?

Tags: angularjs, signalr, signalr-hub

Basically this doesnt work :

```
angular.module('Services')
  .service('SignalrService', [function () {
      var that = this;

      this.pong = function () {
          $.connection.conferenceHub.server.pong(//id);
      }
  }]);
```

And this does :

```
angular.module('Factories')
     .factory('SignalrFactory', [ function () {
         function pong () {
             $.connection.conferenceHub.server.pong(//id);
         }
         return {
             pong : pong
         }
     }
```

Comment: what's the deal of `//id` ?

Comment: If you want comment the `id`  then use: `/* comment */` **`$.connection.conferenceHub.server.pong(/* id */);`**

Comment: its a hardcoded id I am passing, can be anything really

Comment: Are you instantiating the hub connection elsewhere?
What error message?